# Detructors and inherited functions c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

if i have two classes like this:

```
class A
{
   public:
   virtual print(){};
   ~A(){print();}
};
class B:public A
{
   public:
   print(){};
   ~B(){}
};
void main()
{
  B *b1=new B;
  delete b1;
}
```

in the destructor in class A does it call print from class A and not from B because when it is in class A destructor,class B is technically destructed?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Hint: The dtor of A should be virtual, otherwise A* b1 = new B; delete b1; would only call ~A(), not ~B().

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: But that's immaterial. Yes, if the question were different, the answer would be, too, but as it stands the OP just wanted to clarify that base subobjects get destroyed.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I know that,i just didn't add that because i wanted to ask different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thats right. A class is destructed by calling the destructor for itself, and then the destructor for its parent classes, which means by the time you destruct A, B is already gone. You will see similar behaviour if you invoke virtual, overriden functions in your base classes when constructing.

It is generally considered bad practice to call virtual functions in constructors or destructors, as the behaviour, while well-defined, can be misleading to the uninitiated. It's also easy to trip yourself up even if you are initiated.

Comment: i am a little new to c++ so,i was tricked a little bit too until i noticed something that didn't make sense to me,thank you for the tip